# I can’t modify value of a TextInput in a Flatlist

Tags: react-native

I’m currently trying to make my own board with some data that I fetch in my `componentWillMount()`, then, I store this data in a state. Until here, all is normal, I can display my data with some `FlatList`. But, in one of them, I use a `TextInput` to change a quantity value.
When the value is null, I can modify it without any problem. But, when there is a value (store with the fetch), I can’t modify it. When I try, the `TextInput` is replacing it by the default value. I don’t understand because in my `onChangeText`, I’m modifying the value in the array that I use.

I'm developping with React Native and Expo.

```js
<FlatList
  data={state.tableData}
  keyExtractor={item => item.product_id + ""}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
    <View style={[styles.columnRow, { backgroundColor: "#dff2ff" }]}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.textInput}
        maxLength={10}
        textAlign={"center"}
        keyboardType={"numeric"}
        returnKeyType="next"
        blurOnSubmit={false}
        onChangeText={text => {
          let { tableData } = this.state;
          let newQte = "";
          let numbers = "0123456789";

          for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            if (numbers.indexOf(text[i]) > -1) {
              newQte = newQte + text[i];
            } else {
              alert("Veuillez saisir uniquement des chiffres.");
            }
          }
          tableData[index].quantity = newQte;
          this.setState({
            tableData
          });
        }}
        value={item.quantity}
      />
    </View>
  )}
  scrollEnabled={false}
/>;
```

I need to be able to modify the current value and to store it after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're mutating the state object of an item in `onChangeText` in `tableData[index].quantity = newQte`.

However, `FlatList` implements a shallow comparison of state, which means the sub-state `quantity` you're modifying  for an item don't always trigger a render. For some reason it worked with null or undefined, probably due to internal optimizations.

The solution is to completely create a new array without altering the initial state :

```js
<FlatList
  // ...
  onChangeText={text => {
    // this line creates a copy of tableData array
    const copyTableData = [...this.state.tableData];

    let newQte = '';
    let numbers = '0123456789';

    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      if (numbers.indexOf(text[i]) > -1) {
        newQte = newQte + text[i];
        console.log('new qte', newQte);
      } else {
        alert('Veuillez saisir uniquement des chiffres.');
      }
    }

    // we're creating a completely new item object...
    const newItem = {
      ...copyTableData[index],
      quantity: newQte,
    };

    // ... which replace the initial item in our copy
    copyTableData.splice(index, 1, newItem);

    // We're updating the state, with a fresh new array
    // This way React "see" there was a change and re-render the item
    this.setState({
      tableData: copyTableData,
    });
  }}
>
```

Comment: Your solution works. Anyway you are modifying `copyTableData` which you declared `const`. You could define it as `let`, but I prefer the usage of functions that grant immutability, like `slice` that returns a new array: `this.setState({
    tableData: [
      ...tableData.slice(0, index),
      {
        ...tableData[index],
        quantity: newQte,
      },
      ...tableData.slice(index + 1),
    ],
  });`